# Why does linker complain about missing symbols?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, linker

Why am i getting this weird error?
[alt text http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/2203/help.tif](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/2203/help.tif)
Any Ideas?

implementation:

```
#import "VideoView.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@implementation VideoView
@synthesize player;

- (void)playVideoWithURL:(NSURL *)url showControls:(BOOL)showControls {
    if (!player) {
        player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishPlaying:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

        if (!showControls) {
            player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
            player.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;
        }

        [player play];
    }
}

- (IBAction)playVideoWithControls {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [self playVideoWithURL:url showControls:YES];
}


- (void)didFinishPlaying:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (player == [notification object]) {  
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
        [player release];
        player = nil;
    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>


@interface VideoView : UIViewController {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerController *player;
- (IBAction)playVideoWithControls;


@end
```

Answer (score 5):

The MPMoviePlayerController is in MediaPlayer.framework which you forgot to link to.

Comment: What do you mean "link to"? I added it in my .m & .h files

Comment: Double-click on the target under Targets in the Groups & Files tree. On the first tab there is a Linked libraries list, click Plus and add the MediaPlayer framework.

Comment: there we go! thanks for that, never knew how to do that. First time im playing with a framework

Comment: but now im getting an error that claims "[NSCFDictionary playVideoWithControls]: unrecognized selector sent to instance". May someone tell me what that means?

Comment: Daniel Kindler: It means the same thing as your “isEqualToString:” exceptions from before: You sent a message to an object that doesn't respond to that message. More concisely, you sent the message to the wrong object.

Comment: You are sending the message 'playVideoWithControls' to an NSDictionary instance. Start you program in the debugger, it will show you where you got it wrong.

Comment: Well, i switched my "Files owner" to be where im holding my controller, but now i get a new error... "[UIViewController playVideoWithControls]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1028b1" Now i understand its saying that the UIViewController can not respond to that action, but what I'm asking is what else could I do? How could i solve this problem?

Comment: By sending that message to the object that *does* respond to playVideoWithControls. I'm not seeing such a method in the documentation (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/), so you probably need to implement it yourself and then send it to the object you implemented it in.

Comment: Well I did implement it myself. I added my code so you may view

Comment: Don't forget the “send it to the object you implemented it in” part. That would be the VideoView.

Comment: Sorry, im really really new to this. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Help, anyone? I cant figure this out